# Solving $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -x +\frac{A}{x^6}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find a solution for this Ordinary Differential Equation; it is not linear and is of second order so I'm having some troubles to get the solutions.

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -x +\frac{A}{x^6}
\end{equation}

There is a method to solve this kind of equation, or at least I can prove whether  this equation has a solution or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial solution.

$$\begin{equation}
x'' = -x +\frac{A}{x^6}
\end{equation}\tag{1}$$

Multiplying both sides of (1) by $x'(t)$ and integrating the result wrt to $t$, we obtain

$$\begin{equation}
(x')^2 = B+2A\log x -x^2
\end{equation}\tag{2}$$

$$\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{(B+2A\log x -x^2)^{1/2}} = \pm dt
\end{equation}\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

For a proof of solution existence, use the standard theorems (e.g., Picard's), and they will also tell you for which $x$ you can prove existence and uniqueness.

As for trying to solve, put $x_{1} = x, x_{2} = x'$, and sketch the phase portrait of the 1st-order ODE system:
$$
x_{1}' = x_{2}, \quad x_{2}' = -x_{1} - {A \over x_{1}^{6}}.
$$
For $|x_{1}|$ large enough, the term with coefficient $A$ can be neglected or used as a small parameter.  Also try linearization.